# OIL USAGE inside a week?

Tags: oil

I HAVE A 2006 hyundi santa fe I had a service a week ago and drove 350 miles during the week, and already my oil light is on and checked dip stick and it was bone dry!! There is no oil in engine bay or on the ground and no black/blue smoke coming from the exhaust.  Why did my car use 6 litres of oil inside a week?? any Ideas//

Comment: Most likely a leak - is there any sign of oil anywhere it shouldn't be?

Comment: Just because there is no sign of oil on the dip stick, it doesn't mean that the engine is empty of oil.  See how much oil it takes to bring it back to the correct level, then monitor any loss each day.  It could be that they didn't put enough oil in at the service.

Comment: The oil is going somewhere and if it's not pooling on the ground while you are parked, then there is something going on in the engine.  Check your cooling system.  Oil, which is usually at a higher pressure than the coolant, will travel from the oil system to the cooling system through a blown head gasket or cracked block or cylinder head.  You should see oil floating on top of your coolant in the radiator or overflow tank.  The other possibility that comes to mind is that the oil is getting sucked into the combustion chamber and burned.  No smoke is not an indication this isn't happening.

Comment: Check that the sump plug is fully engaged and tight, and/or replace the sump plug washer.